# Prevent external Dialogs from showing in my Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Is there a way to prevent all Dialogs opened by the Android system on certain events to show over my activity when my app is opened? So can I block all the external Dialogs when my app is in the foreground?

Comment: no, you can't .

Comment: Ok thanks @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry but this is not allowed by google